# Mocking a class method that is used via an instance

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to patch a class method using mock as described [in the documentation](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/patch.html#patch). The Mock object itself works fine, but its methods don't: For example, their attributes like `call_count` aren't updated, even though the `method_calls` attribute of the class `Mock` object is. More importantly, their `return_value` attribute is ignored:

```
class Lib:
    """In my actual program, a module that I import"""
    def method(self):
        return "real"

class User:
    """The class I want to test"""
    def run(self):
        l = Lib()
        return l.method()

with patch("__main__.Lib") as mock:
    #mock.return_value = "bla" # This works
    mock.method.return_value = "mock"
    u = User()
    print(u.run())

>>> 
mock
<MagicMock name='Lib().method()' id='39868624'>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: Passing a class `Mock` via the constructor doesn't work either, so this is not really related to the `patch` function.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have found my error: In order to configure the methods of my mock's instances, I have to use `mock().method` instead of `mock.method`.

```
class Lib:
    """In my actual program, a module that I import"""
    def method(self):
        return "real"

class User:
    """The class I want to test"""
    def run(self):
        l = Lib()
        return l.method()

with patch("__main__.Lib") as mock:
    #mock.return_value = "bla" # This works
    mock().method.return_value = "mock"
    u = User()
    print(u.run())
```

Comment: I guess you can mark this answer as the best answer. It solved my problem too.

Comment: Your answer confused me for a moment until I understood that subsequent calls to `mock()` within the context manager would return the same (mock) object each time. I think to make the example a bit less confusing it should use the mock library's intended API as such: `mock.return_value.method.return_value = "mock"`

Answer (score 1):

```
from mock import *

class Lib:
    """In my actual program, a module that I import"""
    def method(self):
        return "real"

class User:
    """The class I want to test"""
    def run(self, m):

        return m.method()

with patch("__main__.Lib") as mock:
    #mock.return_value = "bla" # This works
    mock.method.return_value = "mock"

    print User().run(mock)
```

Comment: This works but I have to pass my mock to every method that I call. Does this approach have any advantage over my own answer that I'm missing?

Comment: `Passing a class Mock via the constructor doesn't work either` I was still working on the solution, I figured I'd at least share part of what I'd accomplished. Btw nice job figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

I mock classmethods like this:

```
def raiser(*args, **kwargs):
    raise forms.ValidationError('foo')
with mock.patch.object(mylib.Commands, 'my_class_method', classmethod(raiser)):
    response=self.admin_client.get(url, data=dict(term='+1000'))
```