# How can I mock a class method of a celery Task

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, celery

Using python 2.7, celery 3.0.24 and mock 1.0.1. I have this:

```
class FancyTask(celery.Task):
    @classmethod
    def helper_method1(cls, name):
        """do some remote request depending on name"""
        return 'foo' + name + 'bar'

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        funcname = self.name.split()[-1]
        bigname = self.helper_method1(funcname)
        return bigname


@celery.task(base=FancyTask)
def task1(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

@celery.task(base=FancyTask)
def task2(*args, **kwargs):
    pass
```

how can I patch `helper_method1` while testing either task?

I've tried something like:

```
 import mock
 from mymodule import tasks

 class TestTasks(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_task1(self):
         task = tasks.task1
         task.helper_method1 = mock.MagickMock(return_value='42')
         res = task.delay('blah')
         task.helper_method1.assert_called_with('blah')
```

and the test is failing. The original function is the one being called. And no, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9728748/253049) didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have a celery instance up and running so it's difficult for me to test this)

The target function in your application code is a classmethod. The function your test code is mocking is an instance method.

Does changing the test_task1 like this help -

```
 def test_task1(self):
     FancyTask.helper_method1 = mock.MagickMock(return_value='42') 
     task = tasks.task1
     res = task.delay('blah')
     task.helper_method1.assert_called_with('blah')
```

You probably also need to change the assert_called_with so it is called from the class level instead of the instance level.

change

```
     task.helper_method1.assert_called_with('blah')
```

to

```
     FancyTask.helper_method1.assert_called_with('blah')
```

Comment: to @rahtanoj: the original `helper_method1` is being called. `delay` schedules the task and a celery worker picks it inmediately. In the worker's output I see a exception raised by the original `helper_method1` because of a `requests.get` to an unreachable host.

Comment: I didn't notice the that helper_method1 was a classmethod. Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: One last change - removed the call to 'classmethod' around mock.

Comment: Same thing, the test failed. Seems to me that somehow the `classmethod` code is buried by celery when registering the Task ([custom classes](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes)).